# How to use Promise.all() on array of promises which take parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

```
let locArr = [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 2, y: 4 }, { x: 6, y: 8 }];

// my asynchronous function that returns a promise
function findLoc(x, y) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let a = setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ x: x * x, y: y * y });
        }, 500);
    });
}

Promise.all([
    // my problem is below
    findLoc(locArr[0].x, locArr[0].y),
    findLoc(locArr[1].x, locArr[1].y),
    findLoc(locArr[2].x, locArr[2].y),
]).then(values => {
    // all values from all the promises
});
```

How can I write the `Promise.all()` function to take parameters from an array of varying size?

I want to pass arguments to the array of promises accepted in the `.all()` method of the `Promise` class. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: This code looks OK at a glance, what's the issue?

Comment: you should create array `const x = locArr.map(a => findLoc(a.x, a.y))` and pass `x` inside Promise.all

Comment: @andy I don't want to hardcode the array values that are passed into the promises

Comment: @indapublic could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: @EmmanuelNK Try this


Promise.all(locArr.map(a => findLoc(a.x, a.y))).then(values => {
  console.log(values);
});

Comment: Use `.map()` to iterate the array, returning an array of promises.  Then, use `Promise.all()` on that array of promises.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `map` instead

```js
let locArr = [{
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}, {
  x: 2,
  y: 4
}, {
  x: 6,
  y: 8
}];

// my asynchronous function that returns a promise
function findLoc(x, y) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let a = setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        x: x * x,
        y: y * y
      });
    }, 500);
  });
}

Promise.all(
  locArr.map(o => findLoc(o.x, o.y))
).then(values => {
  // all values from all the promises
  console.log(values)
});
```

Comment: okay i understand now. I thought about using map but I thought map would run each of the async functions first before running promise.all(). I had made a mistake in writing my map function. I had some confusion there. Thanks!

Comment: How to use `catch` in a situation like this ?

Comment: @TharinduLucky `Promise.all(
  locArr.map(o => findLoc(o.x, o.y))
).then(values => {
  console.log(values)
}).catch(()=>{})` Is this what you want?

Comment: @xianshenglu yeah something like that, but, when I do this, if even one promise is rejected, everything stops and end up in `catch()` right ?

Comment: @TharinduLucky Yeah, that's what `Promise.all` means. It sounds like you need another web api instead of `Promise.all`. So, what do you want? may be [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Comment: @xianshenglu Yeah I understand. Anyway, what I wanted was resolve all the pending promises even one of them failed. However, I achieved it using a `catch()` statement for each individual promise call. Not in `Promise.all()`. It worked for me.

Comment: @TharinduLucky It seems `Promise.allSettled` suit your needs.

Comment: @xianshenglu I didn't really know that. Will try it too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TharinduLucky look out the compatibility. Support from chrome 76+. You might need to configure `babel`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
let locArr = [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 2, y: 4 }, { x: 6, y: 8 }];

// my asynchronous function that returns a promise
function findLoc(x, y) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let a = setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ x: x * x, y: y * y });
        }, 500);
    });
}

Promise.all(
  locArr.map(//map location to promise
    location=>findLoc(location.x,location.y)
  )
).then(values => {
    // all values from all the promises
});
```

Comment: And this adds what additional information, exactly?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's a race condition. Xian's answer wasn't shown when I opened the question. Answer was also in comments but should have been added as answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a trick that requires to modify a little the input of `findLoc`:

```
let locArr = [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 2, y: 4 }, { x: 6, y: 8 }];

// my asynchronous function that returns a promise
// 
function findLoc({x, y}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let a = setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ x: x * x, y: y * y });
        }, 500);
    });
}

Promise.all(locArr.map(findLoc)).then(values => {
    console.log(values);
});
```

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more? Are the input params to findLoc in your answer an object?

Comment: @EmmanuelNK yes, it's actually an object. Object Rest Destructuring helps to remove a step of variable assignment.

Comment: I'm not sure if the right term is "Destructuring assignment". You can read more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0):

Use map, like others said, but also adjust the `findLoc()` function for the simplest reading:

```js
let locArr = [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 2, y: 4 }, { x: 6, y: 8 }];

// my asynchronous function that returns a promise
function findLoc(coordinates) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let a = setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ 
              x: coordinates.x * coordinates.x, 
              y: coordinates.y * coordinates.y 
            });
        }, 500);
    });
}

Promise
    .all(locArr.map(findLoc))
    .then(values => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(values, false, 2));
    });
```